# A flux integral evaluates to zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x,y,z)=(x^2\sin(y^2-z^3),xy^4z+y,e^{-x^2-y^2}+yz)$. Find the flux integral $\int_D F\cdot n  dS$, where $n$ is the outward normal and $D$ is the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ in $z>0$.

I'm applying the divergence theorem. $$div F=2x\sin(y^2-z^3)+4xy^3z+1+y;$$
Let $x=r\cos t,y=r\sin t, z=+\sqrt{r^2-(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{r^2-r^2}=0$. So the integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r\int_0^{z=\sqrt{r^2-x^2+y^2}=0}(2r\cos t\sin (r^2\cos^2t)+1+r\sin t)rdzdrdt,$$ and the inner integral (and so the whole integral) is zero. This makes me doubt I'm doing everything correctly, am I?

---

The fixed integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}(2r\cos t\sin (r^2\cos^2t+(R^2-r^2)^{3/2})+1+r\sin t)rdzdrdt,$$ where the sphere has radius $R$.
But now another problem appears: how to compute $$\int_0^R 2r^2\cos t\sin(r^2\cos^2 t-(R^2-r^2)^{3/2})\sqrt{R^2-r^2}+r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}+r^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\sin t) dt?$$

The second summand can be integrated by substitution $\xi=r^2$, but how about the first and the third summands?

Comment: Be careful when applying the divergence theorem. You need to "close up" the hemisphere with the horizontal disk centered in the origin with radius $r$ before doing anything.

Comment: You have two different $r$'s in play,  The radius of the sphere and your unit in polar coordinates.  They are not the same $r,$ and I suggest you either call them "$R$ and $r$" or "$r$ and $\rho$" or something to keep them straight.  And then $z = \sqrt{R^2 - r^2}$

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: $\sin (y^2 - z^3)$ is something more complicated that you have described.  This integral is going to be messy to attack in any kind of direct way.  I suggest you attack it directly (rather than the divergence theorem) and then consider the symmetry of the vector field (and the symmetry of region) to show that stuff cancels.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881566/divergence-theorem-and-a-hemisphere

Answer (score 1):

$z = \sqrt {r^2 - x^2 - y^2}\\
dS = (\frac {x}{z}, \frac {y}{z}, 1)\ dx\ dy$

$F\cdot dS = \frac {x^3}{z}\sin(y^2+ z^3) + xy^5 + \frac {y^2}{z} + e^{-x^2-y^2} + yz$

Before converting to polar, note that some of these terms are odd.  When we integrate over a symmetric region they will equal 0. i.e.

$\int_{-r}^r \frac {x^3}{z}\sin(y^2+ z^3)\ dx = 0$

Dropping the odd terms we are left with

$\iint \frac {y^2}{\sqrt {r^2 - x^2 - y^2}} + e^{-x^2 - y^2} \ dA$

Now convert to polar and proceed.

If you want to use the divergence theorem, you will need to seal it off.
$\iint F\cdot dS + \iint F\cdot dD = \iiint \nabla \cdot F \ dV$

D is the disk of radius r and the normal points downward $(0,0,-1)$

$\iint F\cdot dS = \iiint \nabla \cdot F \ dV + \iint e^{-x^2-y^2}\ dD$

using the same argument above on the odd terms of $\nabla\cdot F$

$\iiint 1 \ dV + \iint e^{-x^2-y^2} \ dD$

Comment: I think the first two coordinates of the normal should be with a negative sign. Also, why are you talking about integrating over a symmetric region? If we use the definition, the integral is $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R ...$

Comment: $dS = (-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1), -\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac {x}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2}}$  I think my signs are correct.  A hemisphere is symmetric across the $xz$ and $yz$ planes.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, your signs are correct. But I'm still not sure how exactly you apply this symmetry.

Comment: Since integration is linear, you can break up the terms.  For each term decide if you would rather integrate with respect to x first or y first.  In either case the limits are symmetric about $0.$  And integrating an odd function over a symmetric interval yields an a result of $0.$

Comment: Here is anlternate that might be less confusing for you.  You have the intgrand in polar coordinates.  Switch the order of integration to integrate by $\theta$ first.  And many terms will equal 0.

Comment: When applying the divergence theorem, how do you get from $\iint FdS+\iint FdD=\iiint divF dV$ to $\iint FdS=\iiint div F dV+\iint FdD$? Shouldn't it be $\iint FdS=\iiint div F dV-\iint FdD$ instead? Motivated by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881566/divergence-theorem-and-a-hemisphere

Comment: @user5579085 The normal of $dD$ points downward so $\iint F\cdot n\ dD = \iint - e^{-x^2-y^2} \ dD$

Comment: I see, thanks. Does it make any difference if we replace $z > 0$ with $z\ge 0$? And just to clarify, if we use the divergence theorem, using symmetry amounts to crossing out those terms in $div F$ in the integrand for which one of the three substitutions $x\to -x$, $y\to -y$, or $x\to -x$ and $y\to -y$ changes the sign, right? So only the terms of the form $g(x^2,y^2)$ in $divF$ survive, that's how you got $1$ in the last line?